# Flash in Chrome Browser not loading movie

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, google-chrome

Test link http://talentlink.sanscode.com/site/
Seems to work in Firefox and IE, but not in Chrome
Could it be an issue with Chrome not accepting parameters?

AS3 Code

```
import fl.video.VideoEvent;
import fl.video.VideoProgressEvent;
import fl.video.MetadataEvent;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listenLoading);// on enter frame to check if it’s loaded  
function listenLoading(e:Event):void 
{  
    if (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) 
    {  
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, listenLoading);  
        init();
    }  
}

var _params = new Array();

function init()
{
    _params = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
    _video.source = _params.videoSource;
}

_video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY,readyVideo);
function readyVideo(e:VideoEvent)
{
    _video.play();
}
_video.autoRewind = true;
_video.addEventListener(VideoEvent.AUTO_REWOUND,loopVideo);
function loopVideo(e:VideoEvent)
{
    _video.play();
}
```

Comment: Why not use html5 in chrome instead? - http://jsfiddle.net/J4QqD/ you can use a switch to work out if video is supported

Answer (score 0):

### HTML5

Why not Use HTML 5 in chrome with flash as the fallback

### Code

http://jsfiddle.net/J4QqD/

Details on the video tag can be found here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_video.asp

Basically you would put the flash fallback in between the video tags, and use the function i've included in that js fiddle to check whether there is support for MP4 and the video tag. If not, then run the flashembed code

Support detection is from here: http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#video-formats

**update: js fiddle won't save the javascript. here it is again**

```
function supports_h264_baseline_video() {
      if (!supports_video()) { return false; }
      var v = document.createElement("video");
      return v.canPlayType('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"');
}
function supports_video() {
  return !!document.createElement('video').canPlayType;
}

if(!supports_h264_baseline_video()) flashembed....
```

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't play in Safari, either.  i believe the problem is with the use of the Video Component in Flash Professional.

i think that since most of your site is already in HTML you should follow Jason's advice and use the HTML5 Vdeo Tag with Flash as a fallback, but getting the fallback to work first would be ideal.

i would suggest you publish your .swf for FP 10.2+ and code your video object entirely using [StageVideo](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageVideo.html) class instead of using Flash Professional's Video component.  it's much better:  [StageVideo Preview Adobe Max 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=geK7geL3I40)

you could also try using the basic [Video](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html) class instead if you must publish for a lower version of Flash Player than 10.2.